# How to max user experience when the app has a loading time

Tags: android, stream, media-player, user-experience

Ok I have made a simple radio app that streams music from my university radio station. The problem I am having is that the time it takes for the app to prepare the stream causes the play button to appear non responsive.
Details:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    initializeUI();
    setSource();
    preparedNotify();
    prepareMP();  
}

void initializeUI() {...
}

void setSource() {...
}

void prepareMP() {
    mp.prepareAsync();
}
```

As you can see the app starts prepareAsync as soon as onCreate is called, but if the user clicks the play button before it is prepared nothing will happen and thus creating a bad UX.

**So, to the crux of my question: is there anything I can do to either**

**a) reduce the time to prepare the stream**

**b) prevent the user from pressing the button until ready while still maintaining a smooth UX**

Comment: Have you considered replacing the button with a spinning progress indicator until it loads fully, then showing the button?

Comment: How would I go about doing that exactly? The thought had crossed my mind but I have no idea how to translate that into code

Comment: Whenever the user clicked the button, you would display a Spinner view somewhere: http://www.dotnetexpertsforum.com/dialog-box-with-spinner-view-in-android-t1485.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [setOnPreparedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener%29) so that you know when the MediaPlayer is prepared. If the user clicks the play button before it's prepared, you can set some sort of flag like `playWhenPrepared` which you check in that listener and then display some UI like a "Buffering..." dialog. If it's prepared then you can just play.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options in these situations.  First, I'd grey out the play button until the stream was loaded.  This way people won't be annoyed if they click play and nothing happens.  (This is perhaps the most often response to this situation.)  Second, you could think of using a splash screen for your app.  This could slightly annoy users, but it might be a good solution depending on your needs.  The stream will take a while to load: that's just how the internet works, the bits only move so fast.  You could always delay them by providing some sort of toplevel view that did prebuffering, and then allowed users to click on your app whenever it was ready.

Answer (score 0):

You could give the play button a 'pressed state' and set the image to the pressed state from the time it is clicked until onPostExecute. You can also remove the listener during that time

Answer (score 0):

Just going with usual UI for apps like this, I would wait for the user to press the button, than load the stream with a spinning icon in, say... the top left or right corners. Not only would that work for your purposes, but it would also provide the user with a more familiar and intuitive interface. Good luck! -Sam